# Is there a way to wait for Javascript input in R Shiny?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I would like my server to wait until some Javascript returns a result.
Consider the following example code

```
library(shiny)
js <- '
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("bar", function(dummy) {
 Shiny.setInputValue("uniqueid", "Hello back");
}
'

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(tags$script(js)), actionButton("foo", label = "Say hello")))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
 observeEvent(input$foo, {
  session$sendCustomMessage("bar", "hello")
  # it should wait here until uniqueid is no longer NULL
  print(input$uniqueid)
 })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Do another **observeEvent** for **input$uniqueid**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `req()` to the entry:

```
library(shiny)
jss <- 'Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("bar", function(msg) {
  Shiny.setInputValue("uniqueid", "Hello back");
})'

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    tags$script(jss),
    actionButton("foo", label = "Say hello")
  ) 
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$foo, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("bar", "hello")
    req(input$uniqueid)
    # it should wait here until uniqueid is no longer NULL
    print(input$uniqueid)
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```